# Can I use if_else on one column to mutate several other columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have survey data that lists whether an event occurs in one month, or whether it occurs in every month. If a respondent has replied that the event occurs in every month, the individual months are all 0 with a 1 in the same_all_year_round column as below.

```
> dput(df[1:13])
structure(list(jun = c(0, 0, 1, 0), jul = c(0, 0, 0, 0), aug = c(1, 
0, 0, 0), sep = c(0, 0, 0, 0), oct = c(1, 0, 0, 0), nov = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), dec = c(1, 0, 0, 1), jan = c(0, 0, 0, 0), feb = c(1, 
0, 1, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 1, 0), apr = c(1, 0, 0, 0), may = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), same_all_year_round = c(0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

If a respondent has replied that the event occurs in every month, I would like to populate each individual month column with a 1. As below:

```
jun <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
jul <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
aug <- c(1, 1, 0, 0)
sep <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
oct <- c(1, 1, 0, 0)
nov <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
dec <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
jan <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
feb <- c(1, 1, 1, 0)
mar <- c(0, 1, 1, 0)
apr <- c(1, 1, 0, 0)
may <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
same_all_year_round <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, same_all_year_round)
```

I have the following code (that is working) but would prefer to follow the DRY rule. I have just included 3 months for the sake of brevity.

```
    df <- df %>%
  mutate(jul = if_else(same_all_year_round == 1, 1, 0),
         aug = if_else(same_all_year_round == 1, 1, 0),
         sep = if_else(same_all_year_round == 1, 1, 0))
```

Should I be using a version of apply? I've tried a couple of different things but can't seem to make anything work.

Comment: `if_else` returns a vector the same length as it's input. You can't triple the output without tripling the input. But you shouldn't repeat yourself, if all these columns are the same, use `jul = if_else(...), aug = jul, sep = jul)`.

Comment: Or you could use `across` if those columns already exist, something like `mutate(across(jan:dec, ~if_else(same_all_year_round == 1, 1, 0)))`. A little sample input and desired output would make it easier to see what solutions are viable.

Comment: `same_all_year_round` already seems to be dichotomous, please, if possible run `dput(head(df))` and copy the result from the console.

Comment: @GregorThomas, that sounds a lot like what I need to do. I'll add a sample input and output now, just to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: That will be somewhat inefficient because you're still running the same test for every column. If the values are all the same, then `mutate(jun = if_else(...), across(jul:dec, ~ jun))` might work.

Comment: Ah, please post copy/pasteable sample data that we can test solutions on, not pictures of tables. `dput(your_data[1:3])` would be perfect as it is copy/pasteable and includes all class and structure information.

Comment: But we can already see another error--you don't want every month to be `0` if `same_all_year_round` is `0`, you want every month to be unmodified in that case. So `mutate(across(jul:jun, ~if_else(same_all_year_round == 1, 1, .x)))` should work. Untested until suitable test data is included.

Comment: @GregorThomas It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if_else` was misformed because in the case where `same_all_year_round` was **not** `1`, it would set the result to `0`, but your sample output showed that you wanted to not modify the result in that case. We can fix it and apply it to all columns with `across()`:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(jul:jun, ~if_else(same_all_year_round == 1, 1, .x)))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Gregor and @jpdugo17 and thanks for your patience as well. As a newbie, it's greatly appreciated!